# Custom webpart cannot load file or assembly

Tags: 2013, development, asp.net, visual-web-part, visual-studio-2012

My visual webpart is under the namespace `IAA`, and under `IAA.ExtendedControls` I define a few custom ASP.net Control tags to use on my `.ascx` page as follows:

```
namespace IAA.ExtendedControls {
    public class SPTextBox : TextBox {
        public string spColumn { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Then in my `AssemblyInfo.cs` I have:

`[assembly: TagPrefix("IAA.ExtendedControls", "aspExt")]`

And finally on my `.ascx` I have the following:

`<%@ Register Assembly="IAA" Namespace="IAA.ExtendedControls" TagPrefix="aspExt" %>`

`...`

`<aspExt:SPTextBox ID="mytextbox" runat="server" spColumn="spColName" />`

When I deploy the solution and try to use the webpart I get the error:

**Parser Error Message:** `Could not load file or assembly 'IAA' or one of its dependencies. The system could not find the file specified.`

I tried adding the assembly in `Package`, but I get the error that `Both IAA.csproj" and "IAA" contain a file that deploys to the same Package location: IAA.dll`.

I don't want to put my custom tags in a new project. Is there any way to make these tags available from the same namespace as the rest of my project?

Comment: Did you deeply using full trust bin deployment flag?